# How to pass variable as part of string argument of template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is current version of template part but it doesn't work because braces are interpreting as a part of string. How to pass an object.id value instead of string itself?

```
{% with form|with_submit:"SendTransfer,Send Transfer,{{ object.id }}" as submit_form %}
   {% crispy submit_form %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: No, template filters will only take 2 arguments, one is the variable value, the other is an additional parameter. Since you cannot insert anything in additional parameter in template, you can't pass it in. I suggest you doing the concatenation in your views function.

Comment: Have you tried builtin `add` ? so it would be `{% with form|with_submit:"SendTransfer,Send Transfer,"|add:object.id as submit_form %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` template tag suggested in comments is designed for numeric operations:

```
@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def add(value, arg):
    """Adds the arg to the value."""
    try:
        return int(value) + int(arg)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return value + arg
        except Exception:
            return ''
```

I've just wrote my own template tag:

```
@register.filter
def addstr(arg1, arg2):
    """concatenate arg1 & arg2"""
    return unicode(arg1) + unicode(arg2)
```

and used it:

```
{% with "SendTransfer,Отправить перевод,"|addstr:object.id as submit_args %}
    {% with form|with_submit:submit_args as submit_form %}
        {% crispy submit_form %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```